# Why can't use an if statement inside of the inner loop instead of && in insertion sort?

Tags: javascript, insertion-sort

I want to use this code for insertion sort but it's giving the unsorted output:

```
function insertionSort(arr) {
    //insert each element in the right place in the sorted section
    for (let i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        var currentValue = arr[i];
        for (var j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if (arr[j]>currentValue) {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
            }
        }
        arr[j+1] = currentValue;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The correct code:

```
function insertionSort(arr) {
    for (let i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
        let currentValue = arr[i];
        for (var j=i-1; j>=0&&arr[j]>currentValue; j--) {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
        }
        arr[j+1]=currentValue;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I just can't figure out the difference in logic in these two codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the correct code `j--` in the `for()` loop stops decrementing. In your wrong loop `j--` continues decrementing until `j = -1`. Therefore when you do:

```
arr[j+1] = currentValue;
```

In the correct code it would be the last value of `j` when the `if` condition is no longer true.

In your code it will **always** be:

```
arr[0] = currentValue;
```

because the value of `j` is always `-1`.

You can fix it with a `break`:

```
if (arr[j]>currentValue) {
    arr[j+1]=arr[j];
}
else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first implementation the second for loop always runs until the end (until "j" is 0). Since you then use a reference to "j" after the loop to write "currentValue" back the program uses a wrong index.
In the second implementation the loop stops when the next lower entry in the array is not smaller, therefor keeping "j" at the correct index when referred to after the loop.

Generally it is not advised to use the iterator outside of the loop for exactly that reason.